# I couldn't get Krypton Textbox name C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, krypton-toolkit

I have winform project in C#. I add Krypton Toolkits to my project for visual quality. I added TextBox control from Krypton Toolkit. But unfortunately I have a problem with textbox events. I couldn't get Textbox name.

These are my codes :

```
private void TextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tbName = string.Empty;
        // I tried this but it gives me t as null
        //KryptonTextBox t=sender as KryptonTextBox;
        // tbName= t.Name;

        // It gives me textbox name is empty ""
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        tbName = tb.Name;
        tbName = tb.AccessibleName; // give me null
        tbName = tb.Tag.ToString(); // give me null

        // I tried @ Jimi's advice
        Control c = sender as Control;
        tbName = c.Name; // it gives me empty
        tbName = c.AccessibleName; // give me null
        tbName = c.Tag.ToString();// give me null

        // it react like it isn't KryptonToolbox, so passed the if condition.
        if (c is KryptonTextBox)
        {
            tbName = (c as KryptonTextBox).Name; 
        }

        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            tbName = (c as TextBox).Name; // gives me empty.

        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Edit: The way @dr.null has suggested is worked. I added

```
kryptonTextBox1.Textbox.Name="kryptonTextbox1";
```

Comment: Have you tried to cast to `Control` instead? It's the class that defines the `Name` Property. `KryptonTextBox` probably wraps a TextBox, but doesn't directly derive from it.

Comment: @Jimi thanx for attention. If I'm not mistaken, I did what you said. I edited post.But it not worked.

Comment: All right. Anyway, if you set a breakpoint in that event handler and you inspect `sender`, what does the debugger tell you? Is it `null` or some other Type? Did you actually check?

Comment: @Jimi I edited the post. I added a pic while debugging.

Comment: According to the image, you are setting the properties of the `kryptonTextBox1` object not the internal `TextBox`'s. In the ctor, set `kryptonTextBox1.TextBox.Name = "someName";` and the same for other properties of the **TextBox**. Now, cast the `sender` in the `Click` event as `TextBox` and you'll get what you set. `(sender as TextBox).Name` -> `someName`.